# How can I ssh to a remote host from another remote ssh session using perl cgi?

Tags: perl, ssh, cgi, net-ssh

Here is my cgi script using which I can login to ssh1 session but unable to login to another session ssh2 from the remote session ssh1.

```
my $host1=xxx;  
my $host2=xxx;  
my $user=xxx;  
my $pass=xxx;  

//two sessions  
my $ssh1 = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host1);   
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host2);


$ssh1->login($user, $pass); 
//using this, I am able to login to ssh session1 and execute my commands


$ssh1->cmd($ssh2->login($user, $pass));
//I am unable to login the session2($ssh2) from session1($ssh1)
```

Comment: Net::SSH::Perl does not support doing that. [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) does, through the `proxy_command` feature or the never-released-to-CPAN-but-functional [Net::OpenSSH::Gateway](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-OpenSSH-Gateway) module.